# Node.js and Object Oriented Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm creating a game that allows two socket connections with Node.js and Socket.io.  There is a "host" and and "join" function.  First the host connects, but I want to make sure they cannot connect again to another game, so I put in a conditional to check if the game object has been created for that socket.  For some reason, (with the simplified code I used below), the Game object is not saved with the UserSocket object.  I'm assuming it's a scoping issue, but not really sure.

```
function Game(gameid) {

    this.gameID = gameid;
    this.joined = false;
    this.active = false;
    this.baseball = false;

}

function UserSocket(sock) {

    o = this;

    o.sock = sock;

    o.sock.on('clientData', function (data) {

        o.CreateGame(data);

    });

    o.CreateGame = function (hostdata) {

        console.log('in create game');
        --->console.log(o.game); //*** this call always returns null

        if (o.game) {

            console.log('game already started');  // this never happens
            return false;
        }

        newgame = new Game(hostdata);

        console.log("game object created");
        console.log(newgame.gameID);

        newgame.host = o.sock;
        o.game = newgame;

        console.log(o.game);
        arrGames.push(newgame);

        o.SendToHostSocket("Hosting game: " + newgame.gameID );

    } 

}
```

Comment: Is there a reason you aren't using `var` in front of your local variables?  So, all your variables are implicit global variables?  This is probably also the source of your problem because you are overwriting the previous socket object.

Comment: Please show how you are using the code. FYI, if you call UserSocket twice, it impacts the first UserSocket because of what jfriend00 said.

Comment: It only creates UserSocket on connection, but here is the full code:
https://github.com/jpking72/baseballstrat2

Comment: You at least need to change `o = this;` to `var o = this`.

Comment: @jfriend00 Thanks, I only know basic javascript, that is good information

Comment: All variables that are intended to be used only within a function (e.g. `local variables`) should have an initial declaration inside the function that includes `var`.  This defines the variables only within the scope of the function.  If you leave that out, then they become global variables and other code or instances of your object can clobber them which is not what you want.

Answer (score 1):

You at least need to change:

```
function UserSocket(sock) {

    o = this;

    ...
```

to this:

```
function UserSocket(sock) {

    var o = this;

    ...
```

The way you had it, `o` was an implicit global variable.  If anyone called `new UserSocket()` a second time, you would overwrite the value in `o` and then your first socket would no longer work properly.

---

In Javascript all variables that are intended for use only within a function should be preceded with `var` upon their first declaration.  If you leave that out, then they become "implicit global variables" that are accessible to all your code and subject to inadvertently being overwritten.  Implicit global variables are a bad coding practice that often leads to bugs and, in fact, if you run your code in strict mode, this causes an error and the code will not even run.

Comment: @TheHawk - I'm assuming you want to limit it to one game connection `per user`.  You need to be able to identify if a new game request is coming from a specific `user` who already has a game open.  I don't know how you track users in your system because I don't currently see that you are tracking users at all.  That would be required to limit a given user to only one game connection.  The usual way to do that would be by requiring the user to login and your server stored a login id which is required to open a game.  Or, if you don't want to use login, you can put a user id in a cookie.

Comment: I did not know that.  Good stuff.